Migrate WebApplicationFactory class in .NET Core 3.0 to .NET 8.0
My current project is running on .NET Core 3.0 and I want to update it to .NET 8.0.
While updating integration test project, the WebApplicationFactory class causes errors. I have migrated my startup file into the Program.cs file.
This is my code for the WebApplicationFactory class
public class ServiceWorkerFactory<TProgram>
  : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram> where TProgram : class
{

  protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
  {
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
      webBuilder.UseStartup<TProgram>();
    }
      )
               .ConfigureAppConfiguration(
                 (
                   hostingContext,
                   config
                 ) =>
                 {
                   config.AddInMemoryCollection(new[]
                   {
                     new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                       "ConnectionStrings:test",
                       DatabaseTestSetup.test
                     ),
                 
                   });
                 });
  }

  protected override void ConfigureWebHost
  (
    IWebHostBuilder builder
  )
  {

    base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

    builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
      var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
      //Need to pass the tenant id dynamically probably from appconfig

      //Get the integration test application settings
      var integrationTestAppSettings = context.Configuration.GetSection("IntegrationTest").Get<IntegrationTestAppSettings>();
      if (integrationTestAppSettings != null)
      {
        services.AddSingleton(integrationTestAppSettings);
      }
      else
      {
        throw new System.Exception("Integration testing appsetting configuration not found !!");
      }

      var tc = new TaskContext() { TenantId = integrationTestAppSettings.TenantId };

    builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
      services.AddHangfire(options => options.UseMemoryStorage());
      // Mock external dependency
      services.SwapService(Substitute.For<ITestService>());
      
    });
  }
}

I have tried to remove CreateHostBuilder method and put that code in ConfigureWebHost method. That code will work, but it will not consider my in memory config. It will take my appsettings configuration.
Please suggest if I have done anything wrong

"gives error" - what error exactly, can you please add the full text?
